# for Loops Outputing Perimeter of Rectangle in Java

Tags: java

This task our instructor asked us to wrack our brain a bit on(if we wanted to) is to create a program that outputs just the perimeter of a rectangle. The code I've written so far gives me the correct dimensions, but the inner left side gets a single unwanted space. For example if input dimensions were height=4 width=5 builder=x (listed below before code). The task isn't even worth any points. If anyone could help me fix this problem I'm having so it stops teasing my brain; I would greatly appreciate it.

```
xxxxx
 x  x
 x  x
xxxxx

/*
Creating rectangle
*/
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class rectangle
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
     // Declare variables
     String widthString;
     String heightString;
     String builder;
     int width;
     int height;
     int widthCounter;
     int heightCounter;
     //Inputing dimensions and builder
     heightString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter height");
     widthString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter width");
     builder=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter building character");
     //Parsing dimensions
     height=Integer.parseInt(heightString);
     width=Integer.parseInt(widthString);

     for(heightCounter=0; heightCounter<height; heightCounter++)
         {
         for(widthCounter=0; widthCounter<width-2; widthCounter++)
               {
               if(heightCounter==0||heightCounter==height-1)
                  System.out.print(builder);
               if(heightCounter>=1&&heightCounter!=height-1)
                  System.out.print(" ");           
               if(widthCounter==0||widthCounter==width-3)
                  System.out.print(builder);

               }               


         System.out.println();      
         }

   }
}
```

Comment: Start by looking at the `if(heightCounter>=1&&heightCounter!=height-1)` conditional. What happens here when `height = 4` and `heightCounter = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `for` loop with below,

```
    for (heightCounter = 0; heightCounter < height; heightCounter++) {
        for (widthCounter = 0; widthCounter < width; widthCounter++) {
            if (heightCounter == 0 || heightCounter == height - 1)
                System.out.print(builder);
            else if (widthCounter >= 1 && widthCounter < width - 1) //Use widthCounter instead of heightCounter here
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print(builder);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Well, I like think I was sort of close. Makes so much more sense that way. Thank you!